# Spring jpa repository JNDI datasource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, jndi

Hey  everyone am using spring MVC And I want ot integrate JPA Repository with JNDI Data Source , i have an app without jpa repository here's my code :

mvcConfiguration class to create my Datasource :

```
package net.codejava.spring.config;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="net.codejava.spring")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public UserDAO getUserDao() throws NamingException {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)   jndiTemplate.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres2");
    return new UserDAOImpl(dataSource);
}

}
```

this Dao layer that i want to replace with Jpa repository

```
package net.codejava.spring.dao;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import net.codejava.spring.model.User;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
private DataSource dataSource;

public UserDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public List<User> list() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "SELECT * from users";
    List<User> listUser = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<User>() {

        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNumber) throws SQLException  {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            return user;
        }

    });
    return listUser;
}

}
```

and the context.xml

```
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>    
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres2" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb"
      username="postgres" password="root" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>



 </Context>
```

Thanks for any guide  ..

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing this ?

Comment: whats your question ?

Comment: Instead of _JdbcTemplate_, do you want to use JPA implementations in your code ? Plz post what is your question?

Comment: I want ot integrate JPA Repository with JNDI Data Source and i don't know how !!!